# Preload a preprocessed file embedding it in a format

Tags: format-files

I am working on a dictionary, and I would like to reduce the time it takes to build it. The entries that I work with are stored in some form, and are then 'translated' to a TeX file, which is included with `\input`. This file looks like this:

```
\wordentry{book}{a handwritten or printed work of fiction or nonfiction, usually on sheets of paper fastened or bound together within covers}
\wordentry{cat}{an animal that…}
\wordentry{dog}{an animal that…}
```

It's just a series of calls to `\wordentry`, which is defined in the preamble and successfully dumped into the format file. FWIW, this macro calls `\hypertarget`, `\label` and `\bookmark`.

The bulk of the build time is spent processing this file, and I thought that perhaps it would be possible to 'take' it inside the format file I am using. The idea is that, if the following macro

```
\newcommand{\hello}{hello}
```

can be put in the preamble and dumped, then perhaps

```
\newcommand{\thewholefile}{ THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE }
```

could be dumped as well. The same file is processed three times because of cross-references, so any speedup should add up.

Well, I first tried

```
\newcommand{\thewholefile}{\input{thefile}}
```

but the file wasn't being read at all. I messed with `\expandafter` to no avail, so, finally, I just pasted the contents of the file. It worked, although it didn't reduce the build time (it produced a 17MB format file, though). I wonder if I have done it wrong or if dumps simply can't improve the situation. I'm guessing that iniTeX just dumped the definition of `\thewholefile`, without actually 'digesting' it.

Could you please give some hints about the matter? Have I done it wrong, or are format files unsuitable for this task? Is there something I can try to reduce the build time?

I haven't provided a MWE because I saw no way of stripping the monster while keeping its complexity. I guess this question is more 'theoretical' than 'practical'. FWIW, I am using LuajitTeX from TeX Live 2015 (beta-0.80.0).

Comment: As for my problems with `\input`, package [`catchfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) is of help. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/pass-the-contents-of-an-input-command-to-a-macro).

Comment: Some of these macros write both to the screen and to the aux file.  You might be better doing smaller builds until everything is ready.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't (that is, I haven't found a way to) do that; because of the current setup, it's all or nothing.