# How to expand a macro so that it can be used as an input to another macro

Tags: macros, expansion, datatool

I use datatool to get key-value pairs from a data file into a database. I then retrieve values using a custom command, `\varConfig{}`.

One of these values is the number 1, saved as a string in the data file.

My command `\varConfig{}` gives me the number "1" as a string if I use the command in the body of the document.

I want to use that number as an input to another command that generates the path to a file. At the moment I am hard coding it.

```
\input{\reviewfile{1}{conclusions.tex}}
```

But simply replacing the 1 with the `\varConfig{}` command, like this...

```
\input{\reviewfile{\varConfig{report-number}}{conclusions.tex}}
```

... gives me the error

```
illegal parameter number in definition of \reviewfle
```

How do I avoid this error? I'm guessing it is somehow related to expansion, but I have no idea how to use \expandafter appropriately in this case.

edit: I have tried the solutions at [Pass the contents of an \input command to a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/pass-the-contents-of-an-input-command-to-a-macro), for example

```
\expandafter\input\expandafter{\reviewfile{\varConfig{report-number}}{conclusions.tex}}
```

but that just gives me more errors.

edit: MWE

```
\documentclass[9pt,notitlepage]{article}

\RequirePackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{:}% Set the separator between the columns.

% import data from test.csv into a database called 'config'
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{config}{config.csv}

\newcommand{\varConfig}[1]{% 
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\scratchmacro}{value}{config}{key}{#1}%
\DTLifnull{\scratchmacro}{\textbf{ERROR!} key #1 is undefined.}{\scratchmacro}%
}%

% create new command
\newcommand{\reviewfile}[2]{#1/#2}

\begin{document}

\varConfig{block-text}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \caption{\protect\varConfig{short-text}}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        Name:         & \varConfig{block-text}                                \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\varConfig{report-number}

\input{\reviewfile{1}{test.tex}}

%\input{\reviewfile{\varConfig{report-number}}{test.tex}}


\end{document}
```

the data in `config.csv` look like this:

```
short-text: "hello world" 
block-text: "this is some long text to see what happens"
report-number: 1
```

I then have the file 1/test.tex, which is a dummy file containing the text:

```
THIS IS A TEST
```

the output should look like this:
[image: if it works]

Comment: I think the answer might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/pass-the-contents-of-an-input-command-to-a-macro, so will play wiht that a while

Comment: Try (can't myself, because there is no MWE; so it's a wild guess because I have no idea if some of the inner macro is not expandable)... `\edef\tmp{\varConfig{report-number}}` and then use `\reviewfile{\tmp}{...`

Comment: As far as I know DTL commands are not expandable. Even if it's expandable the outer command might not expand it. (case 2 and 3 in [my generic answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646000/250119)) It would be nice if you can send a MWE, so I can minimally modify it to make it work and quickly test it.

Comment: your \varconfig command contains (beside others) a `\hphantom{}`. That can never work in a place where you expect a number.  Use your \varconfig before the \input and then use `\scratchmacro` inside the input (untested due to the lack of MWE).

Comment: Sorry about that - I've added the MWE and confirmed that the `\hphantom{}` is not required. I had a hard time making \varConfig{} fail gracefully so would be willing to rewrite that if required.

Comment: @Rmano - still getting an error. This time `\@dtl@row -> \db@col@id ...`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! Using `\varConfig{report-number}
\input{\reviewfile{\scratchmacro}{test.tex}}` works, but then I have a random "1" just in the middle of my page from the \scratchmacro call. How would I supress that?